# How to point gitbox/git to different local directory

Tags: macos, git, version-control, gitbox

Hi guys I have a remote repository cloned locally, Because my new changes have saved it to a different directory (workspaces in eclipse) I want to point git to the workspace directory rather than the other directory, how do I do this? Gitbox doesn't seem to have any options, and I can't see the .git folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your WORKSPACE do

```
git init
```

and then from where you pulled your copy initially. Do

```
git pull /path/to/your/workspace/project/dir
```